# Testing Voice Recognition App ~ Audio Out to Mic In Adapter

Tags: android, audio, android-virtual-device, voice-recognition

I'm developing an Android voice recognition app for my master thesis.
The app comes with different algorithms that transcribe voice.

To test which of them works best I want to feed the devices microphone with the same speech sample over and over again. I decided to use an open audio book from http://www.librivox.org.

I need an adapter to feed the audio book into my devices microphone input port since the Android VD (Emulator) does not support microphone input.

I have tested a direct connection:

```
AUDIO OUT (LAPTOP) ─────┐
                        ├─[SPLITTER]─────HEADSET PORT (Device)
                   ─────┘
```

* [Splitter](http://www.amazon.de/dp/B007I0NA1Q/)

This does sometimes work on my Sony Xperia ZL even though the quality is really bad.
I also tried an [iRig](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irig/) instead of the splitter - but I think the input for the iRig is only for guitars' line out.

So: Is there a way to feed some audio output to my Android devices microphone input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't manage to feed my real device's mic with audio from my laptop I found a solution.

[image: Test success with Android-x86]

**THE DIGITAL WAY**

**Step 1:** To test my app I now use an [Android-x86](http://android-x86.org) in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) on Ubuntu.
The Android-x86 is a Cyanogen modded Android 4.4 running on (virtual) machines and has microphone support (contrary to the original Android AVD). I tried this on Windows 8.1 but the mic stayed silent.

**Step 2:** I have to map my main audio output channel to a virtual audio input (virtual microphone). I mostly followed the instructions of [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119648&p=12530770#post12530770) using PulseAudio, PulseAudio Volume Control and the magic command: `sudo modprobe snd_aloop`

**Step 3:** Set "Monitor of Built-In Analog Stereo" in PulseAudio Volume Control to standard device. Then set the Host Audio Driver to ALSA and run the machine.

**THE ANALOG WAY**

However I'm not giving up on the cable thing and will update this answer onSuccess().